# How to rebuild Bundle in Capistrano?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, bundler

I have been working up updating a Rails app that uses Rbenv, Bundler, and Capistrano, and after installing Ruby on the remote server, my deploys consistently fail with the following:

```
DEBUG [c642111f]    rake aborted!
DEBUG [c642111f]    LoadError: cannot load such file -- rails/all
DEBUG [c642111f]    /home/deploy/domains/myapp/releases/20151019224651/config/application.rb:3:in `require'
DEBUG [c642111f]    /home/deploy/domains/myapp/releases/20151019224651/config/application.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
DEBUG [c642111f]    /home/deploy/domains/myapp/releases/20151019224651/Rakefile:4:in `require'
DEBUG [c642111f]    /home/deploy/domains/myapp/releases/20151019224651/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
DEBUG [c642111f]    (See full trace by running task with --trace)
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as deploy@myapp.com: rake exit status: 1
rake stdout: Nothing written
rake stderr: rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- rails/all
/home/deploy/domains/myapp/releases/20151019224651/config/application.rb:3:in `require'
/home/deploy/domains/myapp/releases/20151019224651/config/application.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/deploy/domains/myapp/releases/20151019224651/Rakefile:4:in `require'
/home/deploy/domains/myapp/releases/20151019224651/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

SSHKit::Command::Failed: rake exit status: 1
rake stdout: Nothing written
rake stderr: rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- rails/all
/home/deploy/domains/myapp/releases/20151019224651/config/application.rb:3:in `require'
/home/deploy/domains/myapp/releases/20151019224651/config/application.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/deploy/domains/myapp/releases/20151019224651/Rakefile:4:in `require'
/home/deploy/domains/myapp/releases/20151019224651/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Tasks: TOP => deploy:assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing as deploy@myapp.com: rake exit status: 1
rake stdout: Nothing written
rake stderr: rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- rails/all
/home/deploy/domains/myapp/releases/20151019224651/config/application.rb:3:in `require'
/home/deploy/domains/myapp/releases/20151019224651/config/application.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/deploy/domains/myapp/releases/20151019224651/Rakefile:4:in `require'
/home/deploy/domains/myapp/releases/20151019224651/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

If I ssh in to the remote server and try tasks such as `be rails c` from the `releases/20151019224651` path, I get the same messages.

However, I've noticed that once I run `rm -rf .bundle`, all problems go away and everything works great.

The problem is that it's too late to fix the aborted deploy, and every successive deploy attempt runs into the same issue.

What might be going on here, and how can I fix it for good?

Comment: guessing you don't have rbenv in the server env? It looks like it cannot find rails. can you run with --trace and show the full output? also, how is the env on the server different from your local dev machine?

Comment: @Mircea Thanks for taking a look!

Rbenv is installed on the server (it's what I used to update ruby-build and install Ruby 2.2.3). I then ran rbenv rehash, although maybe I'm forgetting a step.

I'm not sure how to run the commands with the trace flag, as they are being run automatically by Capistrano.

The local dev environment is quite different: I develop on Mac OS X, but the server is Ubuntu.